# App service name in Azure DevOps shows No Results Found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

I selected the Azure Subscription that matches the Subscription ID from my app service in Azure Portal, but I keep getting this message No Results Found when I try to select an App Service Name.

Comment: Is you Azure Subscription limited to specific resource group?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej How can I check this? I’ve never used Azure before

Comment: I believe there is a delay between the time you created the app service in Azure portal and it becomes visible in DevOps pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to please check the App type i.e., webapp you created on window, or some other OS based on select the App type. I created my web app on Windows OS and can be able to see the app service name populating over here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yup, one need to go on App Services in the https://portal.azure.com/ and create an app service, then it will be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you Service connection is not limited to resource group. For instace this one is:

[image]

To check this please go to: Project Settings -> Service Connections -> end edit connection to see details.

Resource group should be empty if your choice is to do not limit connection to particular resource group.

So my guess is that your connection is limited to resource group which doesnt have app service.

Answer (score 0):

After doing  all steps above which were mentioned in previous answers, it was still not showing up for me, so I deleted the pipeline and tried again, it works since I was just doing AZ 400 labs, so recreating a pipeline did not take much time.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation. However, when I checked a few minutes later, it was listed. Therefore, I would recommend waiting for a few minutes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35219511)

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of folks mentioned, please wait a few minutes (mileage may vary).
It does take a while to show up in the drop down